# Is difference of two independent Gaussian R.Vs and their sum independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have been trying to answer a question I have been carry on from probability course. I'd appreciate if anyone can help me.

Suppose we have two independent Gaussian distributions, both zero-mean with different variance. Is it true that their difference and their sum are independent from each other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For zero mean random variables $X$ and $Y$ with finite variance:
$$\mathbb{E}((X-Y)(X+Y))=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\textrm{Var}(X)-\textrm{Var}(Y)$$
while
$$\mathbb{E}(X-Y)\mathbb{E}(X+Y)=0.$$

So if the difference and sum are independent then the variances must be the same.